# No text index for collection MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search

I tried to run this simple example to try the example (found on MongoDB Website)on how to use textSearch feauture in Mongo 2.4

```
 <?php
    $m = new Mongo();
    $d = $m->demo;
    $c = $d->planets;

    $c->insert(array("name" => "Mercury", "desc" => "Mercury is the smallest and closest to the Sun"));
    $c->insert(array("name" => "Venus", "desc" => "Venus is the second planet from the Sun, orbiting it every 224.7 Earth days."));
    $c->insert(array("name" => "Earth", "desc" => "Earth is the the densest of the eight planets in the Solar System."));
    $c->insert(array("name" => "Mars", "desc" => "Mars is named after the Roman god of war."));


    $c->ensureIndex(array('desc' => 'text'));

    $r = $d->command(array("text" => "planets", 'search' => "sun" ));
    print_r($r);

    ?>
```

But I got this error:`Array ( [ok] => 0 [errmsg] => no text index for: demo.planets )`
I don't understand why because I already define a text index in this line:

```
$c->ensureIndex(array('desc' => 'text'));
```

and the textSearch is enabled.

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,apparently we need to define before index on the fields (<>text index):

```
$c->ensureIndex(array('name'=> 1,'desc' => 1),array('unique'=> true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly enable the feature before creating a text index or using the text command.

You can enable the text search feature at startup with the textSearchEnabled parameter:

mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true

Comment: As of MongoDB 2.6.x, text search is enabled by default. On MongoDB 2.4.x, you need to enable it as shown above